# Adding Images on gridster from the HTML content on it

Tags: javascript, json, gridster

I am using [Gridster](http://dsmorse.github.io/gridster.js/) for webpage.I have widgets which have text on then.The text is *comma seperated*.Each word in it will be corresponding to an image.I am able to get the text from the widgets in the form of [json](/questions/tagged/json).I just want to *add image* in place of text by sending this text to back-end and getting images from database.
Also the images should be placed on a grid in a way such that the multiple images should not be over one  other.The grids should expand vertically as more and more images comes up.

My main concern is how do I put the images on the widgets according to text on the widgets.

My HTML:

---

```
<div class="gridster">
    <ul>
        <li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">          <textarea class="textareaclass">ABCaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</textarea></li>
        <li data-row="1" data-col="2" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">           <textarea class="textareaclass">ABC</textarea></li>

</div>
```

My JS:

---

```
var gridster;


gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster({
  widget_base_dimensions: [100, 100],
  widget_margins: [5, 5],
  helper: 'clone',
  resize: {
    enabled: true
  }
}).data('gridster');

var json = [{
    "html": "ABC,DEF", //testing this failed
    "col": 1,
    "row": 1,
    "size_y": 2,
    "size_x": 2
}, {
    "html": "Brand1, Small text", 
    "col": 4,
    "row": 1,
    "size_y": 2,
    "size_x": 2
},

{
    "html": "Very big text,ABC",
    "col": 6,
    "row": 1,
    "size_y": 2,
    "size_x": 2
},


{
    "html": "Brand 5,DEF",
    "col": 1,
    "row": 3,
    "size_y": 1,
    "size_x": 1
}, {
    "html": "Brand 5,BAC",
    "col": 4,
    "row": 3,
    "size_y": 1,
    "size_x": 1
},

{
    "html": "Brand 5,Brand 6",
    "col": 6,
    "row": 3,
    "size_y": 1,
    "size_x": 1
}

];

for(var index=0;index<json.length;index++) {
    gridster.add_widget('<li class="new" ><button class="delete-widget-button" style="float: right;">-</button><textarea class="textareaclass">' +json[index].html+ '</textarea></li>',json[index].size_x,json[index].size_y,json[index].col,json[index].row);
}
```

The fiddle which generates json is as follows
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ng02syyc/1/)